# Kentico 9 macro for form field visibility

Tags: macros, kentico

I have a custom page type, and the editor will have the option to enter the following

- Image (from media library)
- Video (from media library)
- YouTube video ID

The field names are as follows

- SlideImage
- SlideVideo
- YouTubeVideoID

So, if an editor ads a SlideImage, SlideVideo and YouTubeVideoID should not be usable. Same for SlideVideo and YouTubeVideoID.

Within the Visibility Condition fields, i'm going to assume a macro is needed for this. My logic is:

This field visible if Field A or B have data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible approach can be to add an additional field, which determines the field that should be used.

Create a text field (let's say, `SlideType`) and use a radio button form control with your options:

```
image;Image
video;Video
youtube;YouTube
```

Tick the "Has depending fields" checkbox for this field, and tick the "Depends on another field" checkbox for the `SlideImage`, `SlideVideo` and `YouTubeVideoID` fields.

Your visibility conditions would then be simplified, instead of checking the values of multiple fields.

For example, the visibility condition for the `SlideVideo` field would be:

```
SlideType == "video"
```

This has a few benefits:

1. Easy to add new fields and configure the visibility conditions
2. Easy to check what needs to be rendered in the front-end - in your repeaters and other webparts, you can simply have conditional statements on the `SlideType` field to determine which field to use
3. Intuitive for the end user - the interface makes it clear which field is being used

Comment: I like this. Great idea. I had changed my approach since I couldn't get the OR statement to work. Asking for a media type is would sove my problems. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to *Visibility condition* in Page type field edit:

```
Fields.SlideImage.Value == String.Empty
```

Do not forget to set proper *Has depending fields* and *Depends on another field* properties depending on your needs. You can learn more about these properties [here](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Reference+-+Field+editor).

Comment: Is this the correct syntax for the OR: Fields.SlideVideo.Value == String.Empty || Fields.YouTubeVideoID.Value == String.Empty

Comment: || for or, && for and, do not forget for brackets for better readability

Comment: The OR condition breaks it. A single condition seems to work fine, adding the || doesn't nothing.

Comment: Can you check macro debug?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the column name on which this value of your depending field is "FirstName", so you can write in the dependent field -> Visibility Condition as

`FirstName.value != ""` 
or

```
FirstName.value
```

You can twist the conditions for as many conditions as possible and can club more than one condition too.

I am also sharing links with you having a lot of examples from Kentico support

[Dependency fields in Kentico](https://devnet.kentico.com/articles/how-to-work-with-depending-fields)

[Using dependency fields in forms](https://devnet.kentico.com/articles/using-dependency-fields-in-forms)

Cheers,
Chetan